# Windows IoT NTLM Authentication to WEb Service

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, windows-authentication, windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to create a UWP application which would access a web service on the local network.  The web service is configured to use Windows authentication.  The application works great when running on a Windows 10 client, but when running on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows IoT 10, the web service returns a 401 - User Not Authenticated.  It would seem the NetworkCredential is not being set correct on the web request when running on the ARM device.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://test/dataservice.svc/Shipments);
        request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("WindowsUser", "WindowsPassword", "DOMAINNAME");
        int readCount = 1;
        Task.Run(async () => {
            try
            {

                var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                    readCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
```